# Java: Making comparisons within a text file

Tags: java, loops, text, comparison

I am currently writing a program where there is a text file with several million digits in it, and I have to go through it looking for a random string of 6 numbers (entered by the user). There are several constraints to this, which is making it difficult.

1. Must used BufferedReader
2. Each character can only be read once (I got it working with a bunch of nested if statements, but the way I did it violated this rule)
3. Cannot use any methods from the string class (so I can't put the read characters together and compare to the original string with .equals()). I have already broken up the original string into the 6 individual characters.
4. Not allowed to store read characters into an array of any kind, only into character variables (of which there should be 6)

Once a match has been found, it is to report the location to the user (I just need to keep a count variable that I increment with every character read) and continue on until the end of the file is reached. There can be multiple matches in the file.

Any help with this would be great, I'm at a loss for what to do.

Comment: Is this a question, or a homework assignment?

Comment: It sounds like you have written code for this, but I don't see any.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `haystack` to search, say `98712365478932145697`, and a `needle` to find, say `893`.

How about:

- use `BufferedReader.read()` to read from the `haystack` a character at a time
- if the character is the first character in your `needle`, store it in the first character variable

  - if the next character is the second character in your `needle`, store it in the second character variable, else, if it's the first character in your `needle`, start over and store it in the first character variable
  - if the next character is the third character in your `needle`, store it in the third character variable, else, if it's the first character in your `needle`, start over
  - etc
- if you fill the last character variable, you have found the `needle` in the `haystack`, you can stop here or start over and look for another occurrence

I won't write the code as it's fairly trivial and this sounds like homework, but that should give you a nudge.

Comment: We need less homework solvers and more people like you on SO. You're encouraging _learning_, which is good.